# Passing textBox to java script function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

My question might be little old but I tried all the possibilities and could not find any solution. 
I want to do one function for verification the input field: 
This function works fine:

```
function myFunction()
{
    var x;
    x = document.getElementById('<%=textBoxCustomerCode.ClientID%>').value;
    if(isNaN(x) || x == "")
    {
        alert('Problem input');
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and here is the code:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imageButtonView" runat="server" Height="60px" ToolTip="بحث" Width="60px" BorderStyle="Solid" ImageUrl="~/Images/searchButton.jpg" OnClick="imageButtonView_Click" OnClientClick="return myFunction();"/>
```

This function works fine but once I need to make the function works with any input field. I want way to pass any field to the function so it will verify it. Any idea to do so.

Comment: you can simply change `document.getElementById` to `document.getElementByClassName` and give that class to any input..

Comment: You could use a `RegularExpressionValidator` for your input textbox.

Comment: I tried it like this x = document.getElementsByClassName("textBoxCustomerCode").value but it always gives undefined value.

Comment: @HussainAhmed It does not work like that. First of all, you need to have elements with the class attribute that you are searching for. Secondly the function returns elementS, as in multiple elements, so you need to pick one or loop through them.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work (making the function work for any textbox):

```
function myFunction(textboxid)
{
    var x;
    x = document.getElementById(textboxid).value;
    if(isNaN(x) || x == "")
    {
        alert('Problem input');
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here you give the function the id of the textbox you want to check. We do not check if a textbox with the given id exists though.

Comment: This is fine but how can I pass it to the function

Comment: I am not sure how asp works, but can't you put some id in the ()'s of myFunction: `OnClientClick="return myFunction();"`?

Answer (score 0):

Change `x = document.getElementById('<%=textBoxCustomerCode.ClientID%>').value;` to `x = document.getElementById('imageButtonView').value;`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use class for finding the element. Or you can pass id to the function in `OnClientClick()`..

```
function myFunction(element)
{
    var x;
    x = document.getElementById('element').value;
    if(isNaN(x) || x == "")
    {
        alert('Problem input');
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and you can call this function by `OnClientClick="return myFunction(this);"`

Answer (score 0):

Try ..........this

```
 function myFunction(id)
 {
     var x;
     x = document.getElementById(id).value;
     if(isNaN(x) || x == "")
     {
       alert('Problem input');
        return false;
      }
      else
      {
        return true;
      }
  }
```

and pass that id through onclientclick event. i.e.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imageButtonView" runat="server" Height="60px" ToolTip="بحث" Width="60px" BorderStyle="Solid" ImageUrl="~/Images/searchButton.jpg" OnClick="imageButtonView_Click" OnClientClick="return myFunction(here is that id to pass);"/>
```

Comment: You can use something like `OnClientClick='return myFunction("<%=imageButtonView.ClientID%>");'

Comment: Can you please help me by writing the full way of passing the element